# Unable to locate the specified class: Model.php codeigniter phpstorm

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, phpstorm

I am trying to add phpstorm autocomplete for codeigniter as seen in different quesiton.

The link provided: https://github.com/topdown/phpStorm-CC-Helpers

I commented out the specified files and added

```
* @property Test_model      $test_model
```

to `my_models.php`

When I try to load `Test_model.php` from my controller using:

```
$this->load->model('Test_model');
```

I get:

> 'Unable to locate the specified class: Model.php'

If I remove the load row and try:

```
$this->Test_model->insert_entry()
```

I get:

> Message: Undefined property: Test::$Test_model

Test.php:

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
  }
  public function modelTutorial(){
    $this->Test_model->insert_entry();
 }
```

Test_model.php

```
class Test_model extends CI_Model{

  public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
  }

  public function insert_entry(){
      die('asdasd');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating models, you need to place the file in `application/models/` and name the file in all `lowercase` - like `yourfile_model.php`

Change your file name from Test_model to `test_model.php` and call it on controller constructor

```
public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('test_model');
  }
```

Read manual [Models](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/models.html)

Comment: The codeigniter tutorial lists model files with 1st letter uppercase. I tried setting file name to lower case: test_model, still same error (Unable to locate the specified class: Model.php)...  Looking at: http://codeigniter.dev/user_guide/general/models.html

Comment: its a class name okk in class name first letter is capital

Comment: Where Model_name is the name of your class. Class names must have the first letter capitalized with the rest of the name lowercase. Make sure your class extends the base Model class.

The file name will be a lower case version of your class name. For example, if your class is this:

Comment: The file name will be a lower case version of your class name

Comment: I can get the model with $this->load->model('test_model') regardless of the file name first letter case, the thing is when I try to add the autocomlete feature for phpstorm I get the Unable to locate the specified class: Model.php. the pulgin instructions are to comment out system/core/Model.php

Comment: Have you removed `die()` function at the beggining of the files (I am not using them, just can't see those are working with `die()` function on the very first line). Edit: @saty CI v.2+ requires lower case file names, CI 3+ requires capital first file names.